# Scala traits,this and that serve for what?

Tags: scala

I am learning SCALA,I do not understand this example

[Understanding Scala Ordered[ ] trait to compare reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40886474/understanding-scala-ordered-trait-to-compare-reference)

```
class Example(var n: Int) extends Ordered[Example] {
  var someVar: String = "default"
  def compare(that: Example) = {
    (this.n) - (that.n) match {
      case 0 => this.someVar.compare(that.someVar)
      case other => other
    }
  }
}
```

this.n is reference to what?that.n is reference to some other variable?Can someone elaborate on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this.n` is a reference to the variable `n` passed to `Example`s primary constructor:

```
class Example(var n: Int)
```

`that.n` is a reference to the variable `n` pointed to by the `that: Example` which is passed to the `compare` method in order to do the comparison:

```
def compare(that: Example)
```